# recyclerView no adapter attach,skipping layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-tabs

I am creating a listview in tabLayout. When I run the app in it says no adapter attach, skipping layout and I cannot see list in emulator; it appears blank. Please help me. I tried almost every answer on internet but could not make it. I can see all other things except list ion the screen.

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.
>   01-02 05:53:38.841 19262-19262/com.example.murarilal.musicmania
>   E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 01-02
>   05:53:38.842 19262-19262/com.example.murarilal.musicmania
>   I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. 01-02 05:53:38.923
>   19262-19278/com.example.murarilal.musicmania E/EGL_emulation: tid
>   19278: eglSurfaceAttrib(1227): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH) 01-02
>   05:53:38.923 19262-19278/com.example.murarilal.musicmania
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
>   0x7632b4a689c0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH 01-02 05:53:38.939
>   19262-19278/com.example.murarilal.musicmania D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0x7632b4a493c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7632b4a0c6a0)

Main activity:

```
public class SongsTab extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<songInfo> songs = new ArrayList<songInfo>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    songAdapter songAdapter1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(songs, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter1);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);


        songAdapter1.setOnitemClickListener(new songAdapter.OnitemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemclick(songAdapter.ViewHolder holder, View v, final songInfo obj, int position) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;

                } else {

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongPath());
                                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        mp.start();
                                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                        Log.d("Prog", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                    }
                                });



                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

                }
            }
        });
        checkUserPermission();

        Thread t = new runThread();
        t.start();
        return v;
    }


    public class runThread extends Thread {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + 1);
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    seekBar.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void checkUserPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},123);
                return;
            }
        }
        loadSongs();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 123:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    loadSongs();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    checkUserPermission();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }

    }

    private void loadSongs(){
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0";
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,selection,null,null);
        if(cursor != null){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    String SongPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                    songInfo s = new songInfo(name,artist,SongPath);
                    songs.add(s);

                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(songs, getActivity());

        }
    }
}

Adapter


public class songAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<songAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    ArrayList<songInfo> songs;
    Context context;
    OnitemClickListener onitemClickListener;

    public songAdapter(ArrayList<songInfo> songs, Context context) {
        this.songs = songs;
        this.context = context;
    }



    public interface OnitemClickListener{
        void onItemclick(ViewHolder holder, View v, songInfo obj, int position);
    }
    public void setOnitemClickListener(OnitemClickListener onitemClickListener)
    {
        this.onitemClickListener=onitemClickListener;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final songInfo song = songs.get(position);
        holder.songName.setText(songs.get(position).getSongName());
        holder.artistName.setText(songs.get(position).getArtistName());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(onitemClickListener!=null)
                {
                    onitemClickListener.onItemclick(holder,view,song,position);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView songName,artistName;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            songName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            artistName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How you found solution?

Comment: yet,i didn't get the solution.

Comment: i dont know whats wrong with this

Answer (score 0):

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter1);
```

add above line after this line 
`songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(songs, getActivity());`

in your `loadSongs()` method

Answer (score 0):

I think this post can help you. Review your code and try setting layoutmanager properly

[USING RECYCLERVIEW](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

Comment: Just copy logcat and post

Comment: If the error is still shown as recyclerView no adapter attach,skipping layout. Try to fix LayoutManager of your recycler view